# How to make spacing between a non-fraction to a fraction the same as fraction to a fraction in math mode?

Tags: math-mode

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}


\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{2}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
SA&= \pi r \sqrt{r^{2}+h^{2}} + \pi r^{2} \tag{1}\\[12pt]
SA&= \pi r \sqrt{r^{2}+\left( \frac{3V}{\pi r^{2}}\right)^{\!2}} + \pi r^{2}\tag{2}\\[12pt]
SA&= \pi r \sqrt{r^{2}+\left( \frac{3V}{\pi r^{2}}\right)^{\!2}} + \pi r^{2}\tag{3}\\[12pt]
SA&= \pi r \sqrt{r^{2}+h^{2}} + \pi r^{2}\tag{4} \\
\end{align*} 
\end{document}
```

There is more white vertical space between (1) and (2) and (3) and (4) than (2) to (3). I belive this is because (2) and (3) have fractions which takes up some of the vertical space. However, this means that the vertical spacing is not equal between all lines. This becomes much more obvious when there are larger fractions or several lines of fractions and no fraction equations. How do I get equal spacing for (1), (2), (3), (4).

[image]

Comment: I don't think that “equal spacing” between equation with different height is so important; much more important is the spacing between the tags: the reader is more focused on the equals signs than to the relative heights of the terms which has to be dealt with case by case with suitable phantoms. Leave out the `[12pt]` bits, they do nothing to improve the typesetting.

Comment: thre is more space betwen (2) and (3)  than between (1) and (2), but you describe it as the other way round?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think I am missing something because for me it looks like there is more white space from (1) to (2) than (2) to (3). To be more specific, for the first case, I am talking about the white space from the bottom of the right hand side of (1) to the top of the square root on the right hand side of (2). For the second case, I am talking about the white space from the pi r ^{2} in the denominator in (2) to the top of the square root in (3).

Comment: @DhruvNair no. the baseline to baseline space is most easily seen looking at the numbers (1) (2) (3) (4)  Tex always tries to keep equal baseline. a row .... has same space as a row AAAA so naturally the A have less space above the A. on your case Tex gave up equal spacing between 2 and 3 and added extra. I forced it to preserve baseline spacing so 2 and 3 got closer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to define `\mystrut` to extend at least as far as your tallest equation, and then add `\mystrut` to each row of the `align`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}


\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{2}
\newcommand\mystrut{\rule[-15pt]{0pt}{30pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
SA&\mystrut= \pi r \sqrt{r^{2}+h^{2}} + \pi r^{2} \tag{1}\\
SA&\mystrut= \pi r \sqrt{r^{2}+\left( \frac{3V}{\pi r^{2}}\right)^{\!2}} + \pi r^{2}\tag{2}\\
SA&\mystrut= \pi r \sqrt{r^{2}+\left( \frac{3V}{\pi r^{2}}\right)^{\!2}} + \pi r^{2}\tag{3}\\
SA&\mystrut= \pi r \sqrt{r^{2}+h^{2}} + \pi r^{2}\tag{4} \\
\end{align*} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, I think you provided the solution for equal spacing between the = signs. Rather, I wanted to know how we can have equal spacing between the actual equations. For example, in your solution, the right hand side of (2) and (3) are much closer together than the right hand side of (1) and (2). I would like for the distance between the right hand side of (1) and (2) to be the same as the distance between the right hand side of (2) and (3) to avoid it looking congested. Thanks again!

Comment: @DhruvNair That would be difficult to achieve because Eqs 1 and 4 have a natural vertical buffer (I'm guessing that which is defined by `\strut`), whereas Eqs 2 and 3, which extend vertically past the confines of `\strut`, do not have the same natural buffer built in.

Comment: @DhruvNair The `tabstackengine` package could use an `\alignShortstack` to get what you are asking...however, `tabstackengine` cannot number individual equations in the stack, which your example requires.

Comment: So what would be the typical etiquette for writing such aligned equations in math using LaTeX. Do people just accept that the spacing cannot be equal or is there some other spacing rule that should be followed. I know there is no hardset rule but I am just asking for math in general and how we would present it. Would it be fine for the right hand side of (2) and (3) being much closer together than the right hand side of (1) and (2)? If not, how would you write this aligned function. Thanks!

Comment: To follow up on `tabstackengine`, with the following in the preamble: `\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\TABstackMathstyle{\displaystyle}
\setstackgap{S}{12pt}`, 12pt will be the interequation gap for short stacks.  Thus, it would be invoked as `\[
\alignShortstack{
SA=& \pi r \sqrt{r^{2}+h^{2}} + \pi r^{2} \\
SA=& \pi r \sqrt{r^{2}+\left( \frac{3V}{\pi r^{2}}\right)^{\!2}} + \pi r^{2}\\
SA=& \pi r \sqrt{r^{2}+\left( \frac{3V}{\pi r^{2}}\right)^{\!2}} + \pi r^{2}\\
SA=& \pi r \sqrt{r^{2}+h^{2}} + \pi r^{2}}
\]`.  Alas, there are no equation numbers.

Comment: @DhruvNair I think typical protocol would be to accept the nominal spacing naturally provided by `align` or maybe to use the equally line-spaced alternative I provide here.

Answer (score 2):

The original spacing

[image]

Has to allow for the varying height and depthand so loses regular baseline spacing, as shown by the log

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}


\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{2}
\showoutput\showboxdepth=3 
\begin{document}

{%\lineskiplimit=-15pt
\begin{align*}
SA&= \pi r \sqrt{r^{2}+h^{2}} + \pi r^{2} \tag{1}\\[12pt]
SA&= \pi r \sqrt{r^{2}+\left( \frac{3V}{\pi r^{2}}\right)^{\!2}} + \pi r^{2}\tag{2}\\[12pt]
SA&= \pi r \sqrt{r^{2}+\left( \frac{3V}{\pi r^{2}}\right)^{\!2}} + \pi r^{2}\tag{3}\\[12pt]
SA&= \pi r \sqrt{r^{2}+h^{2}} + \pi r^{2}\tag{4} \\
\end{align*}}
 
\end{document}
```

with log

```
...\glue(\abovedisplayskip) 24.0
...\glue -3.0
...\glue 0.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 11.70009
...\hbox(20.29991+8.70009)x452.9679, display []
...\penalty 0
...\glue 12.0
...\glue(\lineskip) 4.0
...\hbox(23.6004+12.87993)x452.9679, display []
...\penalty 0
...\glue 12.0
...\glue(\lineskip) 4.0
...\hbox(23.6004+12.87993)x452.9679, display []
...\penalty 0
...\glue 12.0
...\glue(\lineskip) 4.0
...\hbox(20.29991+8.70009)x452.9679, display []
...\penalty 0
...\glue 0.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 3.0
...\hbox(20.29991+8.70009)x452.9679, display []
...\penalty 0
...\glue 0.0
...\penalty 0
...\glue(\belowdisplayskip) 24.0
```

Note the use of `\lineskip` showing that equal space has been added between the rows disregarding the unequal height/depth, so the row spacing varies.

If you set `\lineskiplimit` to -15pt so allowing up to 15pt of potential overlap  then you get

[image]

with log

```
...\glue(\abovedisplayskip) 24.0
...\glue 12.0
...\glue 0.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 11.70009
...\hbox(20.29991+8.70009)x452.9679, display []
...\penalty 0
...\glue 12.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) -0.30049
...\hbox(23.6004+12.87993)x452.9679, display []
...\penalty 0
...\glue 12.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) -4.48033
...\hbox(23.6004+12.87993)x452.9679, display []
...\penalty 0
...\glue 12.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) -1.17984
...\hbox(20.29991+8.70009)x452.9679, display []
...\penalty 0
...\glue 0.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 3.0
...\hbox(20.29991+8.70009)x452.9679, display []
...\penalty 0
...\glue 0.0
...\penalty 0
...\glue(\belowdisplayskip) 24.0
```

Note `\baselinskip` not `\lineskip` in all cases.

Note if you do this, as for forcing even baselin spacing in paragraphs with lareg irregular items in the lines, you will get over-printing wih no warning.

The danger of over printing, and theend result not clearly looking bettr than the original mans that this isn't really ever done in practice. while the (1),(2),(3),(4) hre are evenly vertically spaced, you don't really notice that, what you notice is that lines 2 and 3 look very close together as the linespacing has been forced despite the depth of (2) and the height of (3).

Comment: Thank you! So would the protocol be to leave the spacing to the align function automatically as Steven has said here? Furthermore, @egreg said I should omit the [12pt]. However, my documentation requires double spacing even for equations. But, when I remove the [12pt], despite \setstretch{2} being stated in the preamble, the equations do not look "double spaced" and rather very congested. I randomly decided that [12pt] would be "enough" space but is there a more accurate way of making these equations double spaced?

Comment: tex spacing isn't always perfect and somtimes you need to adjust with `\\[..]` but certainly in his case there is nothing wrong and making the space from the bottom of one line to the top of the next equal should never be an aim. @DhruvNair